# The tenses for itineraries

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

Here is an example about the present simple used for a series of planned actions in a Martinet's grammar book:

> *We **leave** London at 10 next Tuesday and **arrive** Paris at 13. We **spend** two hours in Paris and **leave** again at 15...*

I think this is an itinerary. I wonder whether the present simple is the most appropriate tense for itineraries and whether we can also use the present continuous to talk about it, i.e., We are leaving... and arriving.... We are spending...

Comment: See also https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/163838/using-simple-present-tense-for-future-event-plan-schedule

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible to use the present, or present continuous tense, for actions or events that are planned to happen in the future, the present tense has the virtue of brevity, and avoids the repetitiveness of all those -ing verb endings. You will often see the present used in public notices, timetables, etc, and the present continuous used in descriptions of personal plans.

Comment: I think travel itineraries also belong to personal plans. If we talk about a singular item in an itinerary, I think the present continuous would be appropriate. However, the present simple would be better when we are listing all the items in a travel itinerary, as the verbs without ing is more brief. Am I right?

Comment: It is quite common and OK to use present simple in itinerary, schedule of events etc.