# Which bus are you taking/will you be taking (to mean: "which bus will you be on, tomorrow?)

Tags: word-usage

We were going on a trip. My class was divided into two groups. There were two buses. So my friend wanted to ask me Which bus will you be on tomorrow?"

But is it fine to use:

> Which bus are you taking? (tomorrow)
>
> Which bus will you be taking? (tomorrow)

What sounds natural out of the two?

Thank you:)

Comment: The present tense can be used to describe something that is happening in the future. As such, both verb tenses here are fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Simple present tense for future event / Plan / Schedule](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/163838/using-simple-present-tense-for-future-event-plan-schedule)

Answer (score 3):

They both sound equally natural to me.

Comment: But which one out of the two sounds better to you? Do you think that in this context the first sentence is likely to be used?

Comment: Apples or melons? Which are better? Which are more likely to be eaten? Cars or buses? Which are better? Which are more likely to be used?

Comment: But aren't the sentences kind of similar? I mean just the tenses are different........ So I just asked which tense would be preferred...... That's all......

Comment: And I am replying that there is no general answer to that question. I'm sure there are circumstances in which one would be preferred or the other, but the differences are very subtle, and may depend on the social setting as much as the objective circumstances (eg the nature of the relationship between the people).

Answer (score 1):

They both seem correct to me.

> **Which bus are you taking**  may  be asking about an  arranged activity.
>
> **Which bus will you be taking** seems to be  a polite enquiry.

Here are two links to show the difference

https://dictionaryblog.cambridge.org/2014/06/25/what-are-you-doing-tonight/

https://www.englishgrammarsecrets.com/willbedoing/menu.php

Comment: I think the downvoter needs to read the two links.

Comment: But which one out of the two sounds better to you and more likely?

Comment: If you are particular about the bus, the first one is better. if you want to ask politely the second one is better but not very particular about the bus second one is better

Comment: Which one do you think you might use?

Comment: I _might use_ either one.

Comment: I use which bus will you be taking? It is  polite to ask.