# Are you going to go (to it)?

Tags: word-choice, idiomatic-language

all. In this context, is "go" the standard verb to use? And should I add something to it (to it)?

*And now the funeral's tomorrow... **Are you going to go (to it)?***

Answer (score 1):

In informal conversation "Are you going?" would be perfectly natural. We can use the present tense for future arrangements. [Using Simple present tense for future event / Plan / Schedule](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/163838/using-simple-present-tense-for-future-event-plan-schedule)

In a formal context, you could say "Will you be attending [the funeral]?"

Answer (score 1):

- Are you going? [to it]
- Are you going to go? [to it]

Either is acceptable to show a future intention.